# How to place ImageView's ontop of each other?

Tags: java, android, user-controls, uiimageview

I want to display a play button (ImageView) ontop of a thumbnail (another ImageView). How can I place UI controls ontop of each other?

Programatically or in XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programatically & in XML - but XML is the most preferable way. Just choose a layout manager like [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), and add your ImageViews to it like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_bottom"
    ... />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_ontop"
    ... />
```

Comment: perfect, easy solution, if XML is the way to go, then it's the way to go!

Comment: Why would XML be the most preferable way :-/ ?

Comment: What if I wanted to place a ViewPager on top of an ImageView? Could I achieve this using the same method? So far it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is designed for layering multiple Views on top of each other.

Comment: Yeah, it is - but it can do nothing more than that. This is why I didn't mention it. :)

Comment: Well, you can mix it with other layouts to do lots of things.  It is often the layout you want if you are layering things, but you are right that  RelativeLayout works also in this particular case.